# Generic FunctionalInterface and type erasure

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8

What does the following compilation error mean?

**The method apply(Sample.Foo, capture#5-of ?) in the type FooSetter is not applicable for the arguments (Sample.Foo, 
 capture#6-of ?)**

It occurs in the code below (at the bottom where I've indicated with a comment) which tries to map setters of one bean to the getters of another bean without casting (yes I know there are utilities to do this but this is an example). I use the following two functional interfaces

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FooSetter<V> {
    void apply(Foo foo, V value);
}
```

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface BarGetter<T> {
   T apply(Bar from); 
}
```

```
public class Sample {

public static class Bar{
    public String description;
    public Integer num;

    public String getDecription(){
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String desc){
        this.description = desc;
    }
    public Integer getNum() {
        return num;
    }
    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
}

public static class Foo{

    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public Foo setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public Foo setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Name" + name + "  Age " + age;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {

    HashMap<String, BarGetter<?>> barGetters= Maps.newHashMap();
    barGetters.put("description", (BarGetter<String>)(Bar b) -> b.getDecription());
    barGetters.put("num", (BarGetter<Integer>)(Bar b) -> b.getNum());

    HashMap<String, FooSetter<?>> fooSetters= Maps.newHashMap();
    fooSetters.put("name",   (Foo f, String name) -> f.setName(name));
    fooSetters.put("age",   (Foo f, Integer age) -> f.setAge(age));

    HashMap<String,String> fooFromBar = Maps.newHashMap();
                 // FOO      BAR
    fooFromBar.put("name", "description");
    fooFromBar.put("age", "num");

    Bar bar  = new Bar();
    bar.setDescription("bar desc");
    bar.setNum(5);

    Foo newFoo = new Foo();
    for (String key : fooFromBar.keySet()) {
       //COMPILATION ERROR  
       fooSetters.get(key).apply(newFoo, barGetters.get( fooFromBar.get(key) ).apply(bar) );
    }
 }
}
```

Is there something I'm not seeing here with respect to type erasure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
fooSetters.get(key)
```

returns a value of type `FooSetter<?>`, ie. a `FooSetter` that doesn't know about the type it sets. Its `apply` method therefore has the following (inferred) definition

```
void apply(Foo foo, ? value);
```

You can't use this method with anything (for its second parameter) but `null` (which can be used for any reference type) since you don't know what type it is.

This

```
barGetters.get( fooFromBar.get(key) )
```

returns a value of type `BarGetter<?>`, ie a `BarGetter` that doesn't know what it's getting. Its `apply` method therefore appears as

```
? apply(Bar from);
```

This `?` can be something completely different than what `fooSetter.apply` is expecting.

The type system can therefore not allow it and gives you a compilation error.

Comment: You're the man once again! Thanks for clear explanation.... But, how can I accomplish type safety with respect to the above example? Is it even possible?

Comment: @xtrakBandit No, it is not. You can't know that a `FooSetter` is meant to apply to `Integer` when you have a reference to it of type `FooSetter<?>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a collection of differently-typed generic elements, you need a helper `class` which wraps the actual element and guard it’s access with a runtime-check which replaces the compile-time check that doesn’t work in this case.

E.g.

```
final class FooSetterHolder<T> {
    final Class<T> guard;
    final FooSetter<T> setter;

    FooSetterHolder(Class<T> guard, FooSetter<T> setter) {
        this.guard = guard;
        this.setter = setter;
    }
    <U> FooSetterHolder<U> cast(Class<U> expectedType) {
        if(guard != expectedType) throw new ClassCastException(
            "cannot cast FooSetterHolder<"+guard.getName()
           +"> to FooSetterHolder<"+expectedType.getName()+'>');

        // now that we have checked the type
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") FooSetterHolder<U> h=(FooSetterHolder)this;

        return h;
    }
}
```

You can use this helper class in the following way:

```
HashMap<String, FooSetterHolder<?>> fooSetters= new HashMap<>();
fooSetters.put("name", new FooSetterHolder<>(String.class, Foo::setName));
fooSetters.put("age", new FooSetterHolder<>(Integer.class, Foo::setAge));

FooSetter<String> nameSetter=fooSetters.get("name").cast(String.class).setter;
FooSetter<Integer> ageSetter=fooSetters.get("age").cast(Integer.class).setter;
```

The `cast` method provides an operation which uses the unavoidable unchecked operation internally but performs a runtime comparison of the expected and actual type so that the code using it is type safe (assuming that there are no other unchecked operations).

So the following code won’t be rejected by the compiler

```
FooSetter<Integer> wrong=fooSetters.get("name").cast(Integer.class).setter;
```

but doesn’t create *heap pollution* but rather throws a `ClassCastException` with the message “`cannot cast FooSetterHolder<java.lang.String> to FooSetterHolder<java.lang.Integer>`” very similar to ordinary, non-generic type casts.

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution. I was attempting to get away without any type checking and just end up with magic type safety - clearly not possible. I went something similar using a static conversion function (it was also important to me to have this peice of code not throw exceptions when it came to type casting)                                 `public static <T> T convert(Object object, Class<T> clazz, T defaultValue) {
  if (object != null) {
   return (clazz.isInstance(object)) ? clazz.cast(object) : defaultValue;
  }
  return defaultValue;
 }`